# python selenium not able to open Firefox browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python with selenium. I am getting following error when I am trying to open Firefox using python selenium

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 105, in _wait_until_connectable
    self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\\users\\workshop\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpzcofay Firefox output: 1422716384881\taddons.manager\tDEBUG
\tLoaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]\r\n1422716384882\taddons.manager\tDEBUG\tLoaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeMan
ager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]\r\n1422716384884\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tstartup\r\n1422716384886\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to c:\\users\\workshop\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp
zcofay\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com\r\n1422716384887\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping {F17C1572-C9EC-4e5c-A542-D05CBB5C5A08} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DAP\\DAPFireFox\r\n1422716384887\taddons.xpi\
tINFO\tMapping {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi\r\n1422716384888\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tM
apping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}\r\n1422716384888\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tSkipping una
vailable install location app-system-share\r\n1422716384888\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tSkipping unavailable install location app-system-local\r\n1422716384889\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping {74c841e3-b59f-479e-8
d7a-e26a942a87c8} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt\r\n1422716384889\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping {01A8CA0A-4C96-465b-A49B-65C46FAD54F9} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe Contribu
te CS5.1\\Plugins\\FirefoxPlugin\\{01A8CA0A-4C96-465b-A49B-65C46FAD54F9}\r\n1422716384889\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 10.
0\\Acrobat\\Browser\\WCFirefoxExtn\r\n1422716384889\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping daplinkchecker@speedbit.com to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DAP\\daplinkchecker\r\n1422716384890\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping s
earchpredict@speedbit.com to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SearchPredict\\PRFireFox\r\n1422716384890\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping {0329E7D6-6F54-462D-93F6-F5C3118BADF2} to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SPEEDbit V
ideo Downloader\\SPFireFox\r\n1422716384890\taddons.xpi\tINFO\tMapping adapter@gingersoftware.com to C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ginger\\Mozilla\\adapter@gingersoftware.com\r\n1422716384891\taddons.xpi\t
DEBUG\tcheckForChanges\r\n'
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide path:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ff_profile)
```

Please check if it works for You (it does for me, whereas without path i get same error as You do).

Answer (score 0):

Your selenium version is quite old.

You have to install the latest version 2.53, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to introduce selenium and firefox in your system path then you can use this code, some times depend of the Firefox version that you have you will need install the gekodriver too

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("YOUR_URL")
```

If you didn't introduce them in the system path you can use this other code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")#path of Firefox.exe
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("YOUR_URL")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the correct modules. Don't forget to call them. Check my example below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("Insert URL here")
```

Run that and it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.